# When adding a Documents webpart to a modern page using Powershell, how do I set a property of that webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Specifically, I'm adding a Documents web part using PNP Powershell to a newly created modern page, and would like to set the size of the webpart as part of my script. My current code is

```
Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page $pageName -DefaultWebPartType List -Section 1 -Column 1 -WebPartProperties @{isDocumentLibrary="true";
selectedListId="d81cbf20-0d9e-4adf-75cd-b7aeb2747f0a";
selectedFolderPath="$folderName";
hideCommandBar=$false;}
```

I've tried adding a WebPartProperty of "size" with different options but that doesn't seem to work. I've tried using Get-PnPWebPartProperty to find the name of the size property but that always errors with "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values" even though I'm using the guid of the webpart (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with you when I use Get-PnPWebPartProperty command.

As a workaround, use following pnp powershell to retrieve the properties of document library web part in specific page:

```
$Page= "TestSitePage"
$InstanceId="903cba90-176d-459f-8096-65b6d6f29066"
$Test = Get-PnPPageComponent -Page $Page -InstanceId $InstanceId 
$Test.PropertiesJson
```

And I found there is no size property of document web part, that's why we could not set the size of it via pnp powershell:
[image]

Comment: The webpartHeightKey propery works instead, thanks for that!
1 = small, 2 = medium, 3 = large, but sadly there doesn't seem to be a value for Autosize, which is the one I need

Comment: If you find any reply helpful to you, you could mark it as answer.